# printf concatenation with string given after argument not working

Tags: java, printf, concatenation

I can't make the word "gallon" display using the code given below.

```
paintNeeded = wallArea / PAINT_COVER;
      System.out.printf("Paint needed: %.6f", paintNeeded, "gallons");
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
Paint needed: 0.514286 gallons
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("Paint needed: %.6f gallons", paintNeeded);
```

is what you need.

You should have a *single* format string with all the format specifiers, followed by the arguments to be used for those specifiers.

What you have provided is a format string *without* the word "gallons", followed by *two* arguments, a floating point value and a string, the latter which will certainly be unused. You *could* have tried:

```
System.out.printf("Paint needed: %.6f %s", paintNeeded, "gallons");
```

but that seems a little superfluous to me.